# Git Stash UNTRACKED in IntelliJ

Tags: git, intellij-idea

I use the Git integration in IntelliJ IDEA to stash my changes when i need to do some work on another branch without having to commit.

I noticed that you can stash only modified files (`git stash`) but I'd like to stash also **untracked** files (`git stash -u`). Is it possible inside IntelliJ or I have to do it manually from the console?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Stashing untracked files is not possible in IntelliJ. See https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-62354

Comment: I used manual git stash command instead e.g (`git stash push --include-untracked -m "<insert_your_stash_message>"`)